# How to make collisions in Java?

Tags: java, collision-detection

What is the easiest way to implement collision detection in a maze based Java game? It might be barriers but I think that there might be a better way. Here's my current code:

```
package asa.game.main.tile;
import asa.game.main.gfx.Assets;

public class Wall extends Tile{

    public Wall(int id) {
        super(Assets.wall_one, id);
    }

}
```

Comment: If it's sprites you're using, I would suggest an isOverlapping function that checks the x1,x2 and y1, y2 of this object and the object in isOverlapping( otherObject).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest creating an update thread to call the collision detecting function.  Depending on the shape and size of the player, you can do

wall.getBounds().contains(component.getX(), component.getY())

**This will work if you are using the Swing API (JComponents, JPanels, etc.)**

Also, if you use this, you will need to do a little bit of math involving the size of the components because the x and y values of the components are the top left corner of each.

If you are not using Swing API, and therefore doing some custom painting, there are multiple ways of detecting collision between game objects.  You can assign each object either a radius or a box (depending on the shape of the object) and write your own collision function.  In my personal opinion, I would write a function such as--

save coords of the player
if the coords of the player are in the wall
    move back to previous coords
else
    save new coords of the player

-- It will not seem jumpy because the thread is updating very frequently --

Answer (score 0):

Since you said maze, one thing you can do is define a [`java.awt.Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for each wall segment and for your object moving through the maze.

You can use the intersects method to check if the object has bumped into any of the wall segments.